# What is the policy for a good question, but where the given use case violates a EULA?

Tags: discussion, site-policies, legal

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/193526/change-durability-of-items) asks how to make a custom durability for items in Minecraft. Which itself is a completely ok question, until you get to this part:

> For example, on my vanilla server, donors get an durability
> 99999/99999 renamed diamond pickaxe (with all enchantments on it).

Don't notice the issue? Well Mojang's EULA says that you can't do this. It's not like I'm stretching its meaning either, read it. It basically says to not sell in game items for money. So I was wondering, what's the policy on this? Should the bad part be edited out? Question deleted?

Comment: yes, but actually no. i think the situation of that is a bit different, as i think that is more focused on the entire premise of the question breaking eula rather than only one 
part. The answer for that also assumes that all eulas are indecipherable, which i dont think is fully true, at least not in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We are completely against users asking or answering questions that involve illegal activity.  So much so that if you merely imply that you're pirating a game, your post will be removed.

However, **violating a EULA in and of itself is not illegal**.  We are not here to police contracts which in some jurisdictions are partially or completely unenforceable.  We generally frown on questions or answers that explicitly attempt to violate a ToS or EULA, but can usually find some other reason to remove those posts (i.e. cheating, copyright infringement, etc.).

In this specific case, is the EULA violation central to the question?  No.  Change the group from "donors" to "moderators" and there's no violation.  Is the clause in the EULA that prevents servers from taking donations and conferring benefits on those users something that Mojang/Microsoft even worries about?  Is it even enforceable?  In both cases, the answer is probably no.

Comment: i see, thank you for helping